# data-options="is_hover:true" not working on Foundation 5.2.2

Tags: jquery, dom, tabs, zurb-foundation

I have a set of vertical tabs on Foundation version 5.2.2. The code looks something like this:

```
<div id="projects" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content">
  <h6>Gestión de proyectos</h6>
  <dl class="tabs vertical projects-tabs" data-tab data-options="is_hover:true">
    <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1a">Tab 1</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel2a">Tab 2</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel3a">Tab 3</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel4a">Tab 4</a></dd>
  </dl>
  <div class="tabs-content vertical">
    <div class="content active" id="panel1a">
      <ul class="projects-tabs-links">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2a">
      <ul class="projects-tabs-links">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel3a">
      <ul class="projects-tabs-links">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel4a">
      <ul class="projects-tabs-links">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to show each tab's content when hovering the tab but when I set data-options="is_hover:true" on them, it just won't work. I checked foundation.tab.js to see if everything was OK and everything seems alright.
As you can see in [this link](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/68547c70a88ca71c337b5f8db3d194ca2fff5adc), is_hover support for tabs was added recently.

Do you have any idea why this isn't working?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your example to work once I removed the class f-dropdown from the outer div. You can see my working example here, http://cdpn.io/zgtkG.

If you are not familuer with CodePen, there is a link/button called **Edit this pen** at the bottom. Once you get to the editor you can click on the gear icon next to JS and CSS to see my reference to Foundation 5.2.2.

I hope that helps,
-Adam